# How can I disable Google's offer to post personal photos for businesses?

Tags: photos, privacy, google-maps

The Android Google Maps app observed that I have taken some photos in a toy store. The following day, Google Maps is offering me to post these pictures along with Google's photos for that business.

I have no desire to associate these family photos with the business, or to post personal photos publicly.

Along the offer to post, there was an option to "turn off", but after choosing neither, the option disappeared entirely and I do not see it in Google Maps \ Settings.

I may be on tenuous legal grounds. It may be that if I take a picture inside a toy store or at a restaurant, the rights to the picture belong to the business. Regardless, I'm alarmed by the invasion of privacy with respect to photos on my Android device.

How do I set my Google account or the Android Google Maps app to never offer to post personal pictures on a business's Google Maps page? How do I confirm that I have not inadvertently posted any such pictures in the past?

As an aside, I'm also curious whether Apple blocks iOS apps (in general, not just Google's) from this behavior?

I do wish to continue the automatic backing up of my Android phone photos to Google Drive.

Comment: You can disable the activities that run in the app via terminal

Answer (score 0):

Google Play Maps contains a bunch of activities. The activity that monitors when you take a picture is "com.google.android.apps.gmm.ugc.clientnotification.phototaken.PhotoTakenObserverService"

Look up on how to disable activities on rooted Android because I usually don't disable activities or look for a ROOT app that can perform that function.

Disabling application activities requires ROOT access because your making modifications.

Hope this helps! :)